# Error during Invoking a Stored procedure from UNIX

Tags: unix, stored-procedures, db2

I had a stored procedure with no arguments which was invoked form the UNIX
script by `db2 call` and the SP was working fine and script running fine as well.

The new requirement is to pass a file name to the stored procedure and do some 
business logic -- I am not able to pass the file name from UNIX to the SP. I am using `IN` parameter of `Varchar(50)`.

The SP compiled fine and is available in the correct schema -- I invoked
using multiple ways and none of them are working fine.

Please help me debug this.

DB2 Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ABC.sp_Update(IN FILE_NAME VARCHAR(50))
```

Different methods I tried Calling the DB2 stored proc from the UNIX script

1. `db2 call "ABC.sp_Update("filename.txt")"`
2. `db2 call "ABC.sp_Update(("filename.txt"))"`
3. ```
   FILE_NAME="filename.txt"
   db2 call "ABC.sp_Update($FILE_NAME)"
   ```
4. ```
   FILE_NAME="filename.txt"
   db2 call "ABC.sp_Update($(FILE_NAME))"
   ```

The error I get:

```
db2 call ABC.sp_Update(filename.txt)
SQL0206N  "FILENAME.TXT" is not valid in the context where it
is used.  SQLSTATE=42703
```

When I checked for the execution status of the command I get a return code 4

```
+ RC=4
```

Before the code change, this worked fine:

```
db2 call "ABC.sp_Update()"
```

When I Googled the description of the error `42703`, it is *An undefined column, attribute, or parameter name was detected*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Guys - Should have used a single Quote - It worked - Thanks and sorry

Comment: LOL yes my first question was going to be "did you try a single quote yet?"